# Dual NICs in different subnetworks

Tags: centos, network-interface

My CentOS 7 box has two NICs: `eth0` and `eth1`.

The NICs are in different subnetworks. Each subnetwork has a different DHCP, thus, each NIC is getting a different IP address, with different gateway settings.

My problem is:

When I activate the two NICs with the `nmtui` command, only one NIC is reachable at a time from each respective network.

For example:

I'm `192.168.0.1` I can ping `192.168.0.2` (1st NIC `eth0` of CentOS)
but
I'm `192.168.10.1` I cannot ping  `192.168.10.2` (2nd NIC `eth1` of CentOS)

When I disable `eth0` then I can ping from `192.168.10.1` to `192.168.10.2` (2nd NIC `eth1` of CentOS)

Is this a route issue or am I missing another point?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably both a routing and (in combination with it) an rp_filter issue.

Standard routing is rather dumb. It does not care through which interface a connection was opened but defines (usually only) one next hop for each IP address, usually the default gateway.

Check these settings: `sysctl -a | grep -F .rp_filter` If it is greater than zero for the respective interface then the packet is dropped even before it reaches the firewall.

If you set it to zero then your system may answer correctly but due to firewalls between your system and the target the reply may be dropped because it come from the wrong direction.

A good solution requires the marking of incoming connections for each interface (`iptables` with modules `mark` and `connmark`) separately and using policy routing with these marks (`ip rule`).